# Numbers in the form of 001

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

Is there a special name for numbers in the format of 001. 
For example the number 20 would be 020 and 1 would be 001.
 Its hard to Google around when you don`t know somethings name!
 Since I am already wasting your guys time does any one know a function for changing numbers to this format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is usually called "padding" the number.

Answer (score 3):

Its called left zero padded numbers.

Answer (score 2):

It's called [padding](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/pad-number-zeroes-javascript/).

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're talking about that notation within the context of certain programming languages, `020` as opposed to `20` would be Octal rather than Decimal.

Otherwise, you're referring to padding.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search revealed this nice snippet of code for `Number Padding`:
http://sujithcjose.blogspot.com/2007/10/zero-padding-in-java-script-to-add.html

```
function zeroPad(num,count)
{
  var numZeropad = num + '';
  while(numZeropad.length < count) {
    numZeropad = "0" + numZeropad;
  }
  return numZeropad;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function like:

```
function addZ(n) {
  return (n<10? '00' : n<100? '0' : '') + n;
}
```

Or a more robust function that pads the left hand side with as many of whatever character you like, e.g.

```
function padLeft(n, c, len) {
  var x = ('' + n).length;
  x = (x < ++len)? new Array(len - x) : [];
  return  x.join(c) + n
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Number.prototype.toMinLengthString = function (n) {
    var isNegative = this < 0;
    var number = isNegative ? -1 * this : this;
    for (var i = number.toString().length; i < n; i++) {
        number = '0' + number;
    }
    return (isNegative ? '-' : '') + number;
}
```